# Continuously Updating Operations Dashboard Without Breaking Widgets?

Tags: arcgis-online, operations-dashboard

I am a new user of ESRI's Operations Dashboard and I am experiencing a problem. I am working on a continuously evolving project, so the data in my attribute table changes each day and gets updated every evening. What I am looking for is a way to bring in the new update attribute table data every evening and have my widgets automatically connect to it and work correctly. As of now when I update my attribute table data and republish it online it breaks all of the widget and I have to recreate them all.

If I had a "Data" layer that my widgets were pulling from and I overwrote it with a new layer named "Data" would that fix my problem?

Just trying to save myself from recreating my widgets every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a hosted feature layer, you can overwrite the layer and maintain the widget connection.

Check out https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/manage-hosted-feature-layers.htm and scroll to the 'Overwrite hosted feature layers' section.